# Asp.net dropdownlist cut off in IE

Tags: html

I have a asp:DropDownList with fixed width of 150px, but its list items are not enough to fit in 150px width, so it get cut off in IE (works fine in other browsers)
I search about this, but only got solution for html SELECT.

Comment: asp:DropDownList gets rendered as HTML SELECT when it goes back to the browser, hence whatever solution you found for HTML SELECT can still be applied to the asp:DropDownList

Comment: thanks for this info...
but that solution doesnt satisfy my needs.. i want it same as it rendered in mozilla or chrome

Answer (score 0):

set a css class for your dropdownlist and then set width to that css class

```
<style>
   .myDropDown
   {
       width : 150px;
   }
</style>

<asp:DropDownList CssClass="myDropDown"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**EDIT**

so you must remove width attribute from your dropdownload. then it will be resized depending on items size.

Comment: it will assign width to the dropdown, the problem is ListItems get Cut if they are more than 150px width

Comment: so you must remove width attribute from your dropdownload. then it will be resized depending on items size. response is edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

function SetWidthToAuto(drpLst) {
drpLst.style.width = 'auto';
}

function ResetWidth(drpLst) {
drpLst.style.width = '150px';
}
</script>

<div style="width:150px;overflow:hidden;">
<select id="drpTechnology" style='width:150px' onchange='ResetWidth(this)' onblur='ResetWidth(this)' onmousedown='SetWidthToAuto(this)'>
<option value="-1">Browse me..</option>
<option value="1">Short Option</option>
<option value="2">Little bigger than short Option</option>
<option value="3">Largest option available with this select box</option> </select> <div>
```